# sudo timedatectl timesync-status has high jitter and offset

Tags: time, clock

I've noticed that since the last update of the Ubuntu kernel the OS clock randomly jumps seconds. I noticed that after running a simple Python app which showed that the timestamps on the `print` statements are not in chronological order. Below is an example of `print` of the console and the timestamp of my Django app:

```
[2023-08-28 17:11:00,078: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:01,190: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:02,378: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:03,462: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:04,630: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:05,758: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:07,122: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:08,350: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:09,606: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:10,966: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:10:55,717: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:10:56,938: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:10:58,294: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:10:59,514: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:00,842: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:02,494: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:04,098: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:05,798: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:09,506: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:10,542: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:11,666: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:12,803: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:14,043: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:15,147: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:16,251: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:17,351: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:18,383: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:19,427: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:20,495: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:21,579: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:22,691: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:23,847: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:24,987: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:26,151: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:11,857: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:12,969: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:14,117: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:15,197: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:16,281: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:17,489: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:18,650: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:19,774: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
[2023-08-28 17:11:20,850: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Contato un secondo
```

Opening the Clock application also shows that seconds run, sometimes faster, sometimes slower, and sometimes they jump from a certain number to another.

My Ubuntu server uses `timedatectl` to sync time. Here are the server's details:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
Linux lab01 6.5.0-26-generic #26~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Mar 12 10:22:43 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I can't understand why, but clock jumps a lot. It's like it counts super fast, it figures out the time is wrong, and kind of jumps back. For example, these are two `date` commands with 1 s between them:

```
lab@lab01:~$ date
Mon Mar 25 02:25:24 PM CET 2024
lab@lab01:~$ date
Mon Mar 25 02:25:03 PM CET 2024
```

`sudo timedatectl timesync-status` shows a high jitter and offset values (tens of seconds) but I can't understand why:

```
    Server: 162.159.200.1 (0.pool.ntp.org)
Poll interval: 32s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)
         Leap: normal
      Version: 4
      Stratum: 3
    Reference: A0E080C
    Precision: 1us (-25)
Root distance: 9.864ms (max: 5s)
       Offset: -22.284696s
        Delay: 3.924ms
       Jitter: 10.223410s
 Packet count: 53
    Frequency: +0.000ppm
```

I've also noticed that there are some issues with the `clocksource`:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep clocksource
[    0.026856] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.100958] clocksource: tsc-early: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x2c9485be866, max_idle_ns: 440795258057 ns
[    0.106744] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.146577] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc-early
[    1.765438] clocksource: timekeeping watchdog on CPU1: Marking clocksource 'tsc-early' as unstable because the skew is too large:
[    1.765440] clocksource:                       'refined-jiffies' wd_nsec: 512032000 wd_now: fffedc08 wd_last: fffedb88 mask: ffffffff
[    1.765442] clocksource:                       'tsc-early' cs_nsec: 852454992 cs_now: 9bda08539 cs_last: 9207bcdc0 mask: ffffffffffffffff
[    1.765443] clocksource:                       Clocksource 'tsc-early' skewed 340422992 ns (340 ms) over watchdog 'refined-jiffies' interval of 512032000 ns (512 ms)
[    1.765445] clocksource:                       'tsc-early' is current clocksource.
[    1.765448] tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to clocksource watchdog
[    1.985248] clocksource: Switched to clocksource refined-jiffies
```

I have tried to make `chrony` work with no luck. Currently my `chrony.conf` is:

```
pool 0.pool.ntp.org burst
sourcedir /run/chrony-dhcp
sourcedir /etc/chrony/sources.d
keyfile /etc/chrony/chrony.keys
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
ntsdumpdir /var/lib/chrony
logdir /var/log/chrony
maxupdateskew 100.0
rtcsync
makestep 1 -1
maxdistance 12000
```

I've added the `maxdistance` trying to fix the issue.

The command  `sudo chronyc sources -v` shows the following:

```
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^? ns2.fibertelecom.it           2   6     3    59  -278.5s[-278.5s] +/-   53ms
^? ns3.fibertelecom.it           3   6     3    59  -277.7s[-277.7s] +/-   38ms
^? ns1.fibertelecom.it           2   6     3    60  -276.1s[-276.1s] +/-   35ms
^? nettuno.ntp.irh.it            2   6     3    60  -276.9s[-276.9s] +/-   11ms
```

and `chronyc tracking`:

```
Reference ID    : 00000000 ()
Stratum         : 0
Ref time (UTC)  : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
System time     : 0.000000001 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000000000 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000000000 seconds
Frequency       : 86.704 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.000 ppm
Root delay      : 1.000000000 seconds
Root dispersion : 1.000000000 seconds
Update interval : 0.0 seconds
Leap status     : Not synchronised
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small fix on the grub make it works again

In the `/etc/default/grub` file you must add `tsc=nowatchdog` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

Save and reboot and it should work